# how to increase session time for 7 days

Tags: php, session

i can change the session time on local-host by changing php configuration file.
but i have the problem when i have to change the session on server.
i used the following setting in .config file as

```
 ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
        { 
            session_start(); 
        }
```

also i need where i store session in case of host server

Thanks & Regards

Comment: So and what is th problem? Is it not working?

Comment: i used this on server but session is expire when i get the value from session

Comment: Why not use a cookie??

Comment: ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 7*24*60*60);

// each client should remember their session id for EXACTLY 
session_set_cookie_params(7*24*60*60);

session_start(); look at this

Comment: used session_start(); below ini_set() function as above

Comment: can i store session on server by session path

Comment: Maybe PHP can not change those ini settings during runtime? Try this on your server: `var_dump(ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));` and `var_dump(ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));` and post what it returned.

Comment: it returns string(1) "0" string(4) "1440"